# MySQL: MIN and Group By: Get the first timestamp of 12x # events for each person's day

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to do is to get the smallest `scheduled` time for each `user` in a given day.  For the examples below I've highlighted **just that day's events**, which I will filter on my end simply by adding

```
AND DATE_ADD(scheduled, INTERVAL -$timezone_offset MINUTE)>='$given_day 00:00:00' 
AND DATE_ADD(scheduled, INTERVAL -$timezone_offset MINUTE)< '$next_day 00:00:00'
```

For a simplified example I've got two tables:

```
checkpoints
+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
|   id | type_id | event_id | scheduled           |
+------+---------+----------+---------------------+
| 1111 |       9 |     2222 | 2015-06-05 12:00:00 |
| 1150 |       1 |     2222 | 2015-06-05 10:00:00 |
| 1200 |      11 |     3333 | 2015-06-05 23:00:00 |
| 1305 |       1 |     4444 | 2015-06-05 15:00:00 |
| 1400 |       2 |     4444 | 2015-06-05 05:00:00 |
| 1405 |       3 |     4444 | 2015-06-05 19:00:00 |
| 1500 |       1 |     5555 | 2015-06-05 17:00:00 |
| 1505 |       9 |     5555 | 2015-06-05 18:00:00 |
+------+---------+----------+---------------------+


events
+------+---------+---------------------+
|   id | user_id | start               |
+------+---------+---------------------+
| 2222 |       3 | 2015-06-05 11:00:00 | 
| 3333 |       5 | 2015-06-05 23:00:00 | 
| 4444 |       2 | 2015-06-05 07:00:00 | 
| 5555 |       5 | 2015-06-05 19:00:00 | 
+------+---------+---------------------+
```

I want to query such that I get the following:

```
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
|   id | user_id | start               | scheduled           |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1150 |       3 | 2015-06-05 11:00:00 | 2015-06-05 10:00:00 |
| 1500 |       5 | 2015-06-05 19:00:00 | 2015-06-05 17:00:00 |
| 1400 |       2 | 2015-06-05 07:00:00 | 2015-06-05 05:00:00 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

That is: the first scheduled time of any given driver's day.

The query I thought would work is:

```
SELECT
    checkpoints.id AS id,
    user_id,
    start,
    MIN(scheduled) AS scheduled
FROM checkpoints
    LEFT JOIN events ON event_id=events.id
WHERE DATE_ADD(scheduled, INTERVAL -240 MINUTE)>='2015-06-05 00:00:00' 
    AND DATE_ADD(scheduled, INTERVAL -240 MINUTE)<'2015-06-06 00:00:00'
    AND user_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY user_id, DATE(DATE_ADD(scheduled, INTERVAL -240 MINUTE));
```

The problem is that I'm getting the wrong checkpoint id and start time, even though the user_id and earliest are correct.  To illustrate the problem, I see a result like:

```
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id   | user_id | start               | scheduled           |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 1200 |       5 | 2015-06-05 23:00:00 | 2015-06-05 17:00:00 |
+------+---------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Join on a subquery on user_id, which only has user_id and MIN(scheduled) and keep the same GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

Your query would be illegal for most of SQL implementations. [MySQL allows](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) to `SELECT` columns that are neither aggregated nor included in `GROUP BY` clause.

However, `the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate`

Comment: How do I say "get the complete row with the smallest value of column X for each distinct value of column Y" then?